# How to find missing values ( Like a ? ) in large dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with like 9 different  attributes coloumns, I have to find no of `?` in each attribute . How can I find it ? Kindly help

```
Age 
?
45
67
89
?
56 
78
```

Comment: I think it is better to specify `na.strings= "?"` while reading i.e. `read.table` so that it will be NA and the `class` of the column will be `numeric` instead of `"?"`.  For the specific question, use `as.character(df1$Age ) == "?"`.  For finding it in the whole dataset, `lapply(df1, "==", "?")`

Comment: Or ``which(Age=="?")`` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
#so is the dataframe that has the data
count.q <- function(x) {
      lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\?", x))) %>% sum 
}

apply(so , MARGIN = 2,count.q)

#count.q gets the count of "?" , and I apply it to the columns of the df.
```

For this data -

```
Age ID  Siblings
?   we  1
?   ?   ?
11  ?   0
20  ?   0
```

I got this o/p

```
 Age        ID      Siblings 
       2        3        1
```